# eBay Finding API filter by shipToLocations

Tags: ebay-api

I'm using eBay Finding API and I want to get results by filtering shipping to my country. I found this `shipToLocations`, but I can't find the filter.

```
    $apicall .= "&itemFilter(0).name=Condition";
    $apicall .= "&itemFilter(0).value=New";
    $apicall .= "&itemFilter(1).name=ListingType";
    $apicall .= "&itemFilter(1).value=FixedPrice";
    $apicall .= "&itemFilter(2).name=HideDuplicateItems";
    $apicall .= "&itemFilter(2).value=true";
```

Comment: someone can help?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a new itemFilter with name=AvailableTo and value=<2 Characters code of your country>
For example:

```
$apicall .= "&itemFilter(1).name=AvailableTo";
$apicall .= "&itemFilter(1).value=DE";                  // DE = country code for Germany
```